# How Do I Stop Double Email Alerts?

Tags: notifications, email, gmail

On my Android 2.2 phone, I have the Gmail app and the regular Mail icon on the desktop GUI. Unfortunately when I get a message, I get two alerts, usually about 4 to 15 seconds apart from each other. How can I just get one alert that new mail has come in, not two?

Answer (score 6):

I went into the Gmail app and turned off the alerts there under Settings, reached by the Menu key. That way, they both receive the mail, but only one sends the alert. Don't know why I didn't think of this before, thinking it was going to be much harder.

Comment: more generally, if you used multiple email clients to access the same email account, then you need to turn off notification for all except one of them.